# Directing index.php?page=something into /something BUT ignoring existing files and folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with my Mod_rewrite code. I want it to direct every domain.com/whatever to index.php?page=whatever, I've manager that part. However, I do have some files such as domain.com/admin (and it's subfiles & folders) that I don't want redirected. I also have a file domain.com/nohotlink.png that I also don't want redirected.

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Essentially, I don't want any existing files or folders to redirect - only the ones that don't exist.

Comment: That code you have should already do that. It shouldn't rewrite any real files and folders.

Comment: Interesting, since I can't access the /admin folder. It get's redirected to index.php?page=admin.